# Yii2 leftjoin id таблицы

Tags: mysql, yii2, join, relation

Есть таблица пользователей и таблица записей. У одной записи может быть несколько пользователей. Все это хранится в связанной таблице:

> user_id | item_id | rights

Нужно выбрать всех пользователей для записи а также выбрать права для каждого пользователя записи из связанной таблицы, примерно так

```
public function getUsers()
{
    return $this->hasMany( User::className(), ['id' => 'user_id'])
    ->viaTable('{{%user_items}}', ['item_id' => 'id'])
    ->leftJoin('{{%user_items}}', ['item_id' => $this->id])
    ->select('*');
}
```

Работает, единственно что смущает, это `$this->id`. Если написать '`id`' вместо `$this->id` получаю NULL

Comment: Добавил еще одного пользователя c таким же item_id, теперь не то выбирает :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Попробуйте описать join так:

```
->leftJoin('{{%user_items}}', 'item_id = id')
```

т.е. не массивом а строкой

Comment: Спасибо, уже разобрался. Правда оставил $this->id, т.к. после leftJoin получается id user, а не id item, т.е. в id после leftJoin попадает значение id пользователя, а не id записи.